# File.Delete() throw "owner died" in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, monodevelop

Generally, file deletion can be performed correctly on most Android phones
However, when I run this line of code on "Huawei art-al00x (Android 10.0 - API 29)", the operation throws an exception "owner died"

I can create files and write data, but I can't delete files

I've never been in this situation before

After Google searched, there is still no result

After the second test, I found that if I checked the file in the file manager, I could delete it smoothly, while if I didn't check the file, it would throw an exception

The Code:

```
string path = "Want Save Path";
byte[] buffer = new uint8_t[73790];
using (BinaryWriter BW = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
{
    BW.Write(buffer, 0, (int)exer.Size);
    BW.Flush();
    BW.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("USM:Save Image Data Success");
}
```

StackTrace:

> at System.IO.FileSystem.DeleteFile (System.String fullPath) [0x00065]
> in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Unix.cs:215
> at System.IO.File.Delete (System.String path) [0x0000e]
> in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:107
> at DebugTest.MyView.MainPage_OperateView.TTTFrame_Click () [0x00014]
> in G:\VS2019 Projects\DebugTest\DebugTest\DebugTest\MyView\MainPage_OperateView.xaml.cs:263

Comment: Adding the StackTrace would be a good start

Comment: Add it to the question, make sure its the whole thing

Comment: *"I found that if I checked the file in the file manager, I could delete it smoothly,"* Please explain this comment. Are you saying that you *manually* looked for the file in the file manager, or are you saying that this is a successful programmatic work-around for your problem?

Comment: Can you show the path in the `File.Delete()`? Did you pass a path which is in the windows  not the android?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, I found the file in the file manager
It should be noted that this file is generated through the app and is a BMP image. All I do is open it with the image viewer and view it
After performing the above operations, it seems that the file is unlocked, and I can delete it in my app
If I do not perform the above operations, that exception will be thrown no matter how many times I try to delete the file in the app

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT There is no problem with the file path,this app is not only running on this Android Phones.Other phones can normally delete files in the corresponding path, but only this mobile phone cant do it

Comment: *"this file is generated through the app and is a BMP image."* That suggests the app did not properly release the file. (Is still holding a file handle to it.) Not sure why one device would be more picky than others. Maybe related to GC; that device isn't GC'ing whatever object is holding on to file handle. Show the code where you create that file.